# Using google webtoolkit with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, gwt

I have a page rendered in asp.net. Now I want to use google web toolkit to interact with this page. Is it possible..

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Since GWT is simply compiled down to Javascript, you can use it with any server-side language. You will use the GWT Ajax methods to communicate with your backend.

Answer (score 0):

When working with non-java technology on the server side, you probably should use [JSON RPC](http://code.google.com/intl/nb/webtoolkit/examples/jsonrpc/) to communicate with your logic on the server side.